# How to smoothly save updated data through ASPxComboBox via SelectedIndexChange or SelectedItemChange, etc

Tags: .net, combobox, devexpress, selectedindexchanged

Currently, I have a legacy project that needs improvement, and one particular piece of it is giving me problems. I am new to DevExpress (using 11.2.10 version), and fairly new to current .NET development.

In looking over Stack and the DexExpress support forums and documentation, I have found a lot of things that seemed close to what I am trying to do (mostly involving selectedindexchanged, etc.) but nothing that fits this exactly...

Here is what is going on:

One of the site's pages ("Buttons") allows for editing a lot of information, most of which are neatly grouped together data fields in ASPxRoundPanels, etc.

One of these Round Panels has a ComboBox that shows a list of all the "actions" that a button can do.

The select statement for this (SQL_SelectAllButtonActions) works correctly, pulling up all possible actions from the database's Action table.

The Combo Box (buttonAction) works correctly in pre-selecting from that list the particular value that is stored as an Action_Id on the Button table.

(So far, so good.)

The goal:

The client would like very much to have the page (and database) updated automatically when the Combo Box value is selected by the user.  Without doing a postback, but just by changing the value in the drop-down (combo) box.

So let's say that Button_Id 1 has some values, among them Action_Id 8. If the user were to select a different value via the buttonAction Combo Box, then we should update the record for Button_Id 1 to reflect a new Action_Id value (i.e., not 8).

I have an update command as part of the SqlDataSource (SQL_UpdateButtonAction) which works when tested manually on the database side.

Below is my code, which does not raise errors. But it does not save/update the Action_Id for the button being edited via the Combo Box, either.

What pieces am I missing? All help and suggestions are welcome, and thank you very much!

```
<PanelCollection><dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent1" runat="server"
 SupportsDisabledAttribute="True">
<div class="headerDiv"> 
<div class="buttonDiv">
 <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Save Changes"
 AutoPostBack="False"> 
</dx:ASPxButton>
 </div>

<div style="float: left; width: 390px;"> 
<dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel1" runat="server" Width="400px"
 HeaderText="Details"> 
<PanelCollection>
<dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent3" runat="server">
 <div class="labelDiv"> Action </div>
 <div class="fieldDiv"> 
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="buttonAction" runat="server" Width="240px"
 DataSourceID="ButtonActionsDataSource" TextField="name"
 ValueField="action_id" ValueType="System.Int32"> 
</dx:ASPxComboBox> 
/div>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ButtonActionsDataSource" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:<snip> %>"
 SelectCommand="SQL_SelectAllButtonActions" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
 UpdateCommand="SQL_UpdateButtonAction" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<UpdateParameters> 
<asp:Parameter Name="button_id" Type="Int32" />
<asp:Parameter Name="action_id" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is what it looks like inside my DataClasses files:

```
<Function Name="dbo.Sql_UpdateButtonAction" Method="Sql_UpdateButtonAction">
<Parameter Name="button_id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<Parameter Name="action_id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<Return Type="System.Int32" />
</Function>

<Function Name="dbo.Sql_UpdateButtonItem" Method="Sql_UpdateButtonItem">
<Parameter Name="button_id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<Parameter Name="item_id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
<Return Type="System.Int32" />
</Function>

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.Sql_UpdateButtonAction")]
public int Sql_UpdateButtonAction([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> button_id, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> action_id)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), button_id, action_id);
    return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.Sql_UpdateButtonItem")]
public int Sql_UpdateButtonItem([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> button_id, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> item_id)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), button_id, item_id);
    return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Comment: The methods Sql_UpdateButtonAction and Sql_UpdateButtonItem work correctly yes but when you change the dropdown nothing happens (no postback?)

Comment: Ah, the value in the combo box does change.  But the database values are not changed (and so, if I refresh the page, it reverts to showing the original value.)  Again, no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer that I was given by DevExpress:

Since the client-side SelectedIndexChanged event of both combo boxes was handled, a callback was sent to the ASPxCallback control and the current value was passed as a parameter via the GetValue method.

Also, in the ASPxCallback1_Callback method two additional cases should be added to the switch block. In those cases, the SQL Update command will be called to update data based on the selected value of the currently selected button.